# Not able to access adb in OS X through Terminal, "command not found"

Tags: android, macos, adb

I have installed Android SDK and Eclipse on my Mac system. I am able to program using Eclipse and have created few sample applications. But I am still not able to access `adb` through the terminal window. I have tried following command in terminal:

```
$ pwd
/Users/espireinfolabs/Desktop/soft/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools

$ ls
NOTICE.txt  dexdump     llvm-rs-cc-2
aapt        dx          llvm-rs-cc.txt
adb         lib         source.properties
aidl        llvm-rs-cc

$ adb --help
-bash: adb: command not found
```

I have also added the `ls` output so that you know in which window I am.

Answer (score 684, accepted):

The problem is: **`adb` is not in your `PATH`.** This is where the shell looks for executables. You can check your current `PATH` with `echo $PATH`.

Bash will first try to look for a binary called `adb` in your Path, and not in the current directory. Therefore, if you are currently in the `platform-tools` directory, just call

```
./adb --help
```

The dot is your current directory, and this tells Bash to use `adb` from there.

But actually, **you should add `platform-tools` to your `PATH`**, as well as some other tools that the Android SDK comes with. This is how you do it:

1. Find out where you installed the Android SDK. This might be (where `$HOME` is your user's home directory) one of the following (or verify via *Configure > SDK Manager* in the Android Studio startup screen):

   - Linux: `$HOME/Android/Sdk`
   - macOS: `$HOME/Library/Android/sdk`
2. Find out which shell profile to edit, [depending on which file is used](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html):

   - Linux: typically `$HOME/.bashrc`
   - macOS:  typically `$HOME/.bash_profile`
   - With Zsh: `$HOME/.zshrc`
3. Open the shell profile from step two, and at the bottom of the file, add the following lines. Make sure to replace the path with the one where you installed `platform-tools` if it differs:

   ```
   export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
   export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
   ```
4. Save the profile file, then, re-start the terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc` (or whatever you just modified).

Note that setting `ANDROID_HOME` is required for some third party frameworks, so it does not hurt to add it.

Comment: type "source .bash_profile" or open a new terminal tab after adding that line to start using it inmediately

Comment: To edit the `~/.profile` file in TextEdit, simply enter `open ~/.profile` in Terminal.

Comment: I have heard that "if you have both .profile and .bash_profile files, only the latter gets executed." I would imagine that the path needs to be inserted into `~/.bash_profile` instead of just `~/.profile`.

Comment: Lastly, what worked for me was NOT having the `/:$PATH` at the end of the line.

Comment: @Eptin If you don't add your existing path while exporting a new one, you're not going to be able to use any binaries except for shell builtins or the Android platform tools.

Comment: Just wanted to report that with AndroidStudio the sdk is now included in the Application package. So how would I write out that path?

Comment: @marciokoko I haven't used it, but you can search through the application's files for the `adb` executable.

Comment: I found it, but the problem is that its inside Applications/Android Studio.app/ where there is an sdk folder inside platform-tools. But if I write export PATH=/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH I get this: -bash: export: `Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin': not a valid identifier

Comment: @marciokoko You need to put the path into quotes, e.g. `export PATH="/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH`. Otherwise the space will be treated as a separator.

Comment: I had to write it like this because of the space = export PATH=“/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools”:$PATH but adb devices still returns command not found

Comment: @marciokoko Make sure to restart your shell. Or come to chat and we'll troubleshoot this: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access

Comment: Wow Android Studio has been around since 2011?

Comment: Just Export the path, it 's the simplest way that works.
export PATH=path-to-folder/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools:$PATH

my thx goes to @slhck

Comment: In more recent Android Studio releases: "/Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools" so it will be the following: export PATH="/Users/myuser/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH

Comment: Worked for me, but I need do this every time after restart Android Studio

Comment: @hovo888s Not sure how restarting Android Studio has an effect on this – the PATH should be added to your shell profile (`.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` on OS X, or `.zshrc` for Zsh, etc.). It will then always be available. What doesn't work when you restart Android Studio? Any specific error?

Comment: @hovo888s That doesn't make much sense… if you add the `PATH` to your shell profile it does not automatically disappear. Please ask a new question about this, describe exactly what you are doing, and we'll figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I had to change the first line to export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Library/Android/Sdk" to get it to work.

Comment: @KavindaAthapaththu Yeah, the answer explains that your library may be there as well, see a few paragraphs above.

Answer (score 243):

For `zsh` users. Add `alias adb='/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb'` to `.zshrc` file.

Then run `source ~/.zshrc` command

Comment: This worked for me. Don't forget to `source ~/.zshrc` for the changes to take effect!

Comment: You can use "$USER" instead of <yourUserName>, to make this more dynamic.

Answer (score 150):

1. run command in terminal `nano $HOME/.zshrc`
2. Must include next lines:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
   export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
   export PATH="$HOME/.bin:$PATH"
   export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
   ```
3. Press Ctrl + X to save file in editor,Enter Yes or No and hit Enter key
4. Run `source ~/.zshrc`
5. Check adb in terminal, run `adb`

Comment: step 3 Press Control + X to save file in editor,Enter Yes or No and hit Enter key

Comment: I had to close and start a new terminal after for this to work

Comment: Worked for me in MacOS Monterey Version 12.2.1

Comment: Finalllly, thanks mate worked on Big Sur 11.6.4

Comment: Ln 1 looks like doing the same thing with Ln 4. What is the point? What is the purpose of Ln 3 though?

Comment: worked for me in macbook m1

Comment: worked thanks mac Sonoma 14.2.1

Answer (score 77):

*In addition to slhck, this is what worked for me (mac).*

To check where your sdk is located.

1. Open Android studio and go to:

> File -> Project Structure -> Sdk location

2. Copy the path.
3. Create the hidden `.bash_profile` in your home.
4. (open it with `vim`, or `open -e`) with the following:

---

```
export PATH=/Users/<Your session name>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/<Your session name>/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
```

---

5. Then simply use this in your terminal: `. ~/.bash_profile`

[SO post on how to find adb devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x)

Answer (score 67):

## Quick Answer

Pasting this command in terminal solves the issue in most cases:

### ** For Current Terminal Session:

- *(in macOS)* **export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH**
- *(in Windows)* *i will update asap*

### ** Permanently:

- *(in macOS)* edit the `~/.bash_profile` using `vi ~/.bash_profile` and add this line to it: **export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH**

However, if not, continue reading.

---

## Detailed Answer

*Android Debug Bridge*, or *adb* for short, is usually located in *Platform Tools* and comes with 
*Android SDK*, You simply need to add its location to system path. So system knows about it, and can use it if necessary.

#### Find ADB's Location

Path to this folder varies by installation scenario, but common ones are:

---

- If you have installed **Android Studio**, path to ADB would be: *(Most Common)*

  - *(in macOS)* **~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools**
  - *(in Windows)* *i will update asap*

---

- If you have installed **Android Studio** somewhere else, determine its location by going to:

  - *(in macOS)* **Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance And Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK** and pay attention to the box that says: **Android SDK Location**
  - *(in Windows)* *i will update asap*

---

- However Android SDK could be Installed without Android studio, in this case your path might be different, and depends on your installation.

---

#### Add it to System Path

When you have determined ADB's location, add it to system, follow this syntax and type it in terminal:

- *(in macOS)*

  export PATH="your/path/to/adb/here":$PATH

  for example: **export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH**

Comment: "Permanently" worked. Long story short for it:
1. vi ~/.bash_profile
2. export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
3. :x

Comment: `vi something else` use the console editor for opening the file, you can also use `open ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Thanks for the exact answer. Other's answers are very much confusing.

Answer (score 53):

[image]This is how it worked for me

first I find my platform-tools than I was using zshrc instead of bash_profile so I run this command first

```
echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/' >> ~/.zshrc
```

next refresh terminal

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Check if it worked

```
adb devices
```

result of this command must be something similar to this if so then it worked.

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So simple just copy / paste!

Comment: The perfect answer would be this one.

Answer (score 51):

I don't know how did you install the android SDK. But in Mac OS, what really worked for me is to reinstall it using brew. All problems solved in a row.

```
brew install --cask android-sdk
```

Later on:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter 'platform-tools'
```

Like a charm

Comment: For all mac users this is absolutely top answer for the problem, like it is in this thread -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901692/set-up-adb-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Use `brew cask install android-platform-tools` works as well

Comment: It's been updated to `brew cask install android-sdk`
_source_: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2706

Comment: It's been updated to `brew install --cask android-platform-tools`

Comment: @Lehlohonolo_Isaac is this command replacing both commands?

Comment: @eMarine No, it's only for replacing the first command. 
For the second one, you can use `brew install --cask android-sdk`.

Look up https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/android-sdk#default for more

Answer (score 43):

If you have installed Android Studio on MAC here is how:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

or

```
open ~/.zshrc in VScode
```

Then edit the file

```
# Android ADB
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

control + X  OR Save file.
Restart Terminal and try

```
> adb
```

Comment: clean solution. Worked first time.

Comment: Also worked on mac os big sur

Comment: working solution

Comment: didn't do a thing

Comment: @htafoya are you using bash or zshrc ? if bash then change the above command from .zshrc to  .bash_profile

Answer (score 36):

For me, I ran into this issue after switching over from bash to zsh so I could get my console to look all awesome fantastic-ish with [Hyper](https://hyper.is/) and the [snazzy](https://github.com/sindresorhus/hyper-snazzy#hyper-snazzy) theme. I was trying to run my react-native application using `react-native run-android` and running into the op's issue. Adding the following into my `~.zshrc` file solved the issue for me:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 32):

## UPDATE

As @Loren.A mentioned in comment latest version of brew does not support `cast`. So one can simply use:

`brew install android-platform-tools`

---

1. Simply install adb with brew

   `brew cask install android-platform-tools`
2. Check if adb is installed

   `adb devices`

Comment: This appears to be the easiest solution. The current version of `brew` doesn't use `cask` so the command that worked for me is `brew install android-platform-tools`

Comment: now you only need to install homebrew, and probably upgrade python

Answer (score 21):

If you are using the Mac with the M1 chip add the below export command to the zshrc file using the nano command, if that file is not present the nano command will create it for you so run

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

paste this path in that file without any modification

```
export PATH="/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
```

hit ctrl-x and then Hit y to save the changes and the hit return Key to close it without renaming the file.

then run

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

to refresh the .zshrc file

and then try runnning

`adb`

it should give you the desired output

Answer (score 13):

If you are using `zsh` on an OS X, you have to edit the zshrc file.

Use vim or your favorite text editor to open zshrc file:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

Paste the path to `adb` in this file:

```
export PATH="/Users/{$USER}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
```

Comment: nano ~/.zshrc
export PATH="/Users/{$USER}/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH

Comment: For me I had to use my username i.e. `sonusourav` in place of `{$USER}` probably because `USER` was not defined

Answer (score 6):

**For Mac OS Catalina or Mojave**

Enter command to open nano editor

```
nano $HOME/.zshrc
```

Set PATH variable, means append more path as shown here

```
FLUTTER_HOME="/Users/pankaj/Library/Android/flutter-sdk/flutter/bin"
DART_HOME="/Users/pankaj/Library/Android/flutter-sdk/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
ANDROID_SDK_HOME="/Users/pankaj/Library/Android/sdk"
ANDROID_ADB_HOME="/Users/pankaj/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"

PATH="$PATH:$FLUTTER_HOME"
PATH="$PATH:$DART_HOME"
PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME"
PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_ADB_HOME"
```

Now press Command + X to save file in editor,Enter Yes or No and hit Enter key.

Comment: This is a great answer

Comment: great answer. would be great to add little more context behind why ".zshrc" or  ".zprofile" works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784894/macos-catalina-10-15beta-why-is-bash-profile-not-sourced-by-my-shell

Answer (score 6):

**This worked for me on my MAC - 2020**

Go to directory containing adb:

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
```

Run adb command to list all services

```
./adb shell dumpsys activity services
```

Comment: Short and clean solution worked in first attempt

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get the stupid path working so I created an alias for abd

```
alias abd ="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb"
```

works fine.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac, Android Studio 3.6.1, I added this to .bash_profile

`export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools":$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

Or the alternative solution could be

1. Make sure you already install for android SDK. Usually it is located under
   /Users/your-user-name/Library/Android/sdk
2. If the SDK is there then run this command. ./platform-tools/adb install your-apk-location
3. From there you can generate the APK file That's the only sample to check if adb 
   command is there

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I had to add sdk directory in the path for 2nd step: ./Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb install ~/Downloads/apk-release.apk

Answer (score 1):

For some reason when installed `Android Studio 3.6.1` the `adb` file was actually in `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/platform-tools`. not sure if this is a bug with my installation or what but this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac Os the default shell has moved on to "zsh" from "bash" as of Mojave and later releases, so for all the Mac users I would suggest go with the creating ".zshrc" file. "adb" runs as it is intended to be. Thanks @slhck for your info.!

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps below

- Open bash_profile using *open -e .bash_profile*
- write
  *export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"*
- close bash_profile file
- run *source .bash_profile*
- Done run your adb command now !!

In some cases, you may need to run *source .bash_profile* every time you open cmd to run adb commands

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was opening the **terminal settings** and changing the **shell path** from /bin/bash to /bin/zsh
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -13):

It's working fine..

```
brew install android-sdk
```

Later on:

```
android update sdk --no-ui --filter 'platform-tools'
```

Comment: Slightly similar at my answer don't you think?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out because you never mentioned "Like a charm"