# how to read '/data/anr/traces.txt' in samsung S2

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am developing an application and it keeps crashes randomly. I finally catch the logcat when it crashes.

here are the lines I got

```
01-30 01:04:47.281    2856-2856/com.snappext:hascode_process I/System.out﹕ Done
01-30 01:05:02.617    2856-2861/com.snappext:hascode_process I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-30 01:05:02.640    2856-2861/com.snappext:hascode_process I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-30 01:05:39.304    2750-2752/com.snappext D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 830K, 14% free 11618K/13383K, paused 1ms+3ms
```

now I need to know how to read '/data/anr/traces.txt' I am using my Samsung S2 for testing

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read a text file in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use this cmd

```
adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt
```

you will need to navigate to adb folder under android installation

Comment: If you get permission denied with this, check out @Russ answer about other trace files.

Answer (score 5):

You might try to do a `adb shell "ls /data/anr"` which will list all the the trace files in that directory. Atleast on my device I don't have permission to list the `/data` folder but I do for `/data/anr`

On my LG G3, despite the message saying it wrote to `/data/anr/traces.txt` it would in fact keep several. Could be Xamarin/Mono I'm developing with doing this but the file I needed was actually `/data/anr/traces_<PKG_NAME>.txt` where `<PKG_NAME>` is the Android Package of the App but with each `.` replaced with a `_` (ex: `com.my.project` -> `com_my_project`).

It also kept other trace files, presumably for non-debugging apps, with the pattern `traces00.txt`, `traces01.txt`, ... `traces10.txt`. In short there wasn't a 'normal' `traces.txt` file in that folder, but many starting with 'traces' and ending in '.txt'

Comment: Worth highlighting this answer because I get permission denied tying to access traces.txt but I *can* access the other trace files that are specific to my app. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Windows:

1. Open cmd / terminal
2. `cd` to SDK folder ([see: Find SDK location from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34541883/2819864))

   - Windows: `cd c:/android-sdk`
   - OSX: `cd /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk`
3. `cd platform-tools`
4. `adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt`
5. Check c:/android-sdk/platform-tools/traces.txt

On step 4 you can get some errors:

- [adb not found in OS X terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7609388/2819864)
- [error:more than one device and emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654718/how-to-use-adb-shell-when-multiple-devices-are-connected-fails-with-error-mor)