# Logcat not working on MAC

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, logcat

Ive recently started on Android programming and I just want to print a simple text on console. Seems that Logcat is the fastest way to do that, however its not working on MAC. What is missing?

```
Log.d("MYTAG", "PRINT");
```

[image]

Comment: 1) is the app running 2) is the logcat showing output for the correct device 3) are the filters correct

Comment: Use the "RUN" tab instead

Comment: 1) app running and that line of code executed
2) yes and thats the only device running
3) yes as shown on the picture

tried to see msgs on RUN tab but there are none related to my TAG

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, especially on emulator devices, ADB can get stuck and stop working. Try going to `Terminal` tab and typing `adb kill-server`. Restart your app with `control`+`D`/`R` and you should be good to go

Comment: Are you working on windows machine? If so, you may want to follow these steps  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44525706/4733231

Comment: no... as said on the question, its not working on my mac

Comment: Oops, sorry, it's the end of working day here. Did you correctly install Android studio? Because ADB should've been added to your path by default installer. Anyways, here's how to do it manually https://stackoverflow.com/a/7609388/4733231