# macOS Catalina 10.15(beta) - Why is ~/.bash_profile not sourced by my shell?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, zsh, macos-catalina

I want to set the environment variable I added below the line to `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` but it didn't work.

```
export JBOSS_HOME=/Users/{USERNAME}/Desktop/jboss7
```

Afterward, exit the terminal and open it again when executing `echo $JBOSS_HOME` I get nothing.

[image]

Comment: I guess .bash_profile has not been sourced. Are you sure that your terminal creates a bash **login** shell? If not, .bash_profile would be ignored.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes that's right.I don't know why the default bash is changed?!!

Comment: I don't get it. What "default" is changed? You did not say, which Terminal program you are using, but ususally you can configure the Terminal application how to start the shell.

Comment: @user1934428 I didn't know there is the various shell.

Comment: Apple replaces bash with zsh as the default shell in macOS Catalina https://stackoverflow.com/a/59151321/5788247

Answer (score 377, accepted):

Apple has changed the default shell to zsh. Therefore you have to rename your configuration files. `.bashrc` is now `.zshrc` and `.bash_profile` is now `.zprofile`.

Comment: Apple changed from bash to zshell due to licensing concerns. https://thenextweb.com/dd/2019/06/04/why-does-macos-catalina-use-zsh-instead-of-bash-licensing/

Comment: It's such an awesome user experience how my dev setup breaks with every OS-X upgrade

Comment: @ChrisHatton I just keep waiting for the next update so that I can break my current setup and start everything from scratch nonce again, looking forward for the next release!

Comment: I'm using bash, `.bashrc` is loaded but `bash_profile` is not. I ended up adding `[ -f ~/.bash_profile ] && source ~/.bash_profile` to `.bashrc` and deleting a chunk, generated by `conda init bash`, in `.bash_profile` that source `.bashrc`. Is it just me having the same problem?

Comment: I was searching for this all over internet. This worked for me. Thankyou.

Answer (score 69):

If you for some reason (as me) don't want to rename/move your `~/.bash_profile` file you can do the next things:

1. Create a new file `~/.zprofile`
2. Type there `source ~/.bash_profile`
3. Save and close
4. Run a new terminal session

Answer (score 8):

You can just copy your existing bash_profile and name it zprofile and it will work fine.

- Run the below command in terminal and you are set after closing and opening new terminal.

`cp ~/.bash_profile ~/.zprofile`

Comment: Be aware that if you've, e.g., run Brew since the change to zsh you may have content in that .zprofile that you want to keep. Better to concatenate the two than ovewrite.

Answer (score 5):

I created a new file called

`/usr/local/bin/mybash`

which contains a wrapper script:

`/usr/local/bin/bash --init-file $HOME/.bashrc`

I installed this local/bin/bash from [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh).

**Full Sequence of Events**

```
brew install bash
echo "/usr/local/bin/bash --init-file $HOME/.bashrc" > /usr/local/bin/mybash
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mybash
```

Then I opened the settings for `terminal.app` [cmd-comma]. Under the `General` Tab, select the radio button for `Command (complete path)`

In the text box change the text from `/bin/zsh/` to `/usr/local/bin/bash`.

[image: Example of final format]

Comment: This is a good option, as the above answers do not take into consideration that certain syntax are different in zsh and bash.

Answer (score 3):

After you close a Terminal window, variables you set in that window are no longer available. If you want the value of a variable to persist across sessions and in all Terminal windows, you must set it in a shell startup script. For information about modifying your zsh shell startup script to keep variables and other settings across multiple sessions, see the “Invocation” section of the [zsh man page](http://x-man-page://zsh).

You can use `~/.zlogin` to add your variables.

Check out [this reference](https://support.apple.com/en-ae/guide/terminal/apd382cc5fa-4f58-4449-b20a-41c53c006f8f/mac).

Answer (score 1):

changing the bash profile to zsh profile works and source it as well to see in action.

```
vikas@Vikas-Kumar ~ % mv .bash_profile .zsh_profile
vikas@Vikas-Kumar ~ % source .zsh_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simbolic link and keep your .bash_profile file with this:

```
ln -s .bash_profile .zsh_profile
source .zsh_profile
```

Any changes in .bash_profile will be reflected in .zsh_profile

Comment: I am getting ln: .zsh_profile: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 1):

Even with os Catalina */bin/bash* comes for free, brew is not needed. Simply create your *.bash_profile* and set shell in terminal settings to */bin/bash*. it automatically finds your .bash_profile. *z-shell* is not *bash-shell* and simply renaming will work in most cases but definitely is not correct.

Comment: This answer did the trick for me by switching from `/bin/zsh` to `/bin/bash` in the terminal setting. Apple's article gave me the why: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050.  I think staying with `bash` on machines utilized for software development makes sense for max compatibility with console based dev-tools.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to update the file, zsh is mac's default, put this in terminal. e.g.:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score -3):

```
cp zprofile ~/.zprofile
```

Add to `.zprofile`:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

eg. by `>vi .zprofile`

Done