# Mac OSX - adding export to .bash_profile doesn't work

Tags: macos, terminal

I clean installed MacOSX (Catalina) and created and added the following to `~/.bash_profile`

```
export HOSTNAME=USDNE001
```

Then I tried to close and open Terminal app but I get nothing when I do

```
echo $HOSTNAME
```

Not sure why this doesn't work for me.  This is a clean install of MacOSX and there is no file called `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`.

Comment: `HOSTNAME` is automatically set when the shell is started; you shouldn't be setting it manually. Changing it won't affect, for example, the output of the `hostname` command.

Comment: Are you sure you are still using `bash`? The default login shell is now `zsh`, which (unsurprisingly) won't use `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56784894/macos-catalina-10-15beta-why-is-bash-profile-not-sourced-by-my-shell