# Cake -> AdbInstall -> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: android, xamarin, cakebuild

How can I use cake ADB in the right way?

My laptop -> Mackbook M1

```cs
#addin "nuget:?package=Cake.Xamarin&version=3.0.2"
#addin "nuget:?package=Cake.Android.Adb&version=3.2.0"
#addin "nuget:?package=Cake.Android.SdkManager&version=3.0.2"

const string NEXUS_GO_ANDROID = "/Users/***/***.Android.csproj";


Task("Test")
  .Does(() => 
  {
      FilePath androidApk = BuildAndroidApk(projectFile: NEXUS_GO_ANDROID, sign: true, configuration: "Debug", configurator: null);
      //FilePath androidApk = BuildAndroidApk(projectFile: NEXUS_GO_ANDROID, sign: false, configuration: "Debug", configurator: null);
      Console.WriteLine($"!!! android APK {androidApk}");
      //AdbUninstall("uk.co.pallex.nexusgo");
      AdbInstall(apkFile: androidApk);
  });
 
RunTarget("Test");
```

```sh
>dotnet cake

...
Time Elapsed 00:00:06.48
!!! android APK /Users/***/***.Android/bin/Debug/***-Signed.apk
An error occurred when executing task 'Test'.
Error: One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
        Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

My goal is to build once and run apk in two enumerators(where one is LTR and second is RTL). But now I can't run even on one of them.

How can I fix that? Update to another version? Set some global properties?

## Update

for get more information we need run `dotnet cake --verbosity=diagnostic`

```sh
Could not resolve path for tool "adb" using these directories: /usr/local/bin,/usr/bin,/bin,/usr/sbin,/sbin,/usr/local/share/dotnet,~/.dotnet/tools,/Library/Apple/usr/bin,/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands,/opt/homebrew/bin,/opt/homebrew/sbin
Could not resolve path for tool "adb.exe" using these directories: /usr/local/bin,/usr/bin,/bin,/usr/sbin,/sbin,/usr/local/share/dotnet,~/.dotnet/tools,/Library/Apple/usr/bin,/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands,/opt/homebrew/bin,/opt/homebrew/sbin
An error occurred when executing task 'Test'.
Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Cake.AndroidAdb.AdbTool.GetAlternativeToolPaths(AdbToolSettings settings)
   at Cake.Core.Tooling.Tool`1.GetToolPathUsingToolService(TSettings settings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Tooling\Tool.cs:line 285
   at Cake.Core.Tooling.Tool`1.GetToolPath(TSettings settings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Tooling\Tool.cs:line 266
   at Cake.Core.Tooling.Tool`1.RunProcess(TSettings settings, ProcessArgumentBuilder arguments, ProcessSettings processSettings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Tooling\Tool.cs:line 160
   at Cake.Core.Tooling.Tool`1.Run(TSettings settings, ProcessArgumentBuilder arguments, ProcessSettings processSettings, Action`1 postAction) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Tooling\Tool.cs:line 81
   at Cake.Core.Tooling.Tool`1.Run(TSettings settings, ProcessArgumentBuilder arguments) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Tooling\Tool.cs:line 60
   at Cake.AndroidAdb.AdbTool.Uninstall(String packageName, Boolean keepDataAndCacheDirs, AdbToolSettings settings)
   at Cake.AndroidAdb.AdbAliases.AdbUninstall(ICakeContext context, String packageName, Boolean keepDataAndCacheDirs, AdbToolSettings settings)
   at Submission#0.AdbUninstall(String packageName, Boolean keepDataAndCacheDirs, AdbToolSettings settings)
   at Submission#0.<<Initialize>>b__0_4()
   at Cake.Core.CakeTaskBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<Does>b__0(ICakeContext _) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeTaskBuilder.Execution.cs:line 26
   at Cake.Core.CakeTaskBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<Does>b__0(ICakeContext context) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeTaskBuilder.Execution.cs:line 81
   at Cake.Core.CakeTask.Execute(ICakeContext context) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeTask.cs:line 119
   at Cake.Core.DefaultExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync(CakeTask task, ICakeContext context) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\DefaultExecutionStrategy.cs:line 72
   at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.ExecuteTaskAsync(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, Stopwatch stopWatch, CakeTask task, CakeReport report) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeEngine.cs:line 278
   at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.ExecuteTaskAsync(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, Stopwatch stopWatch, CakeTask task, CakeReport report) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeEngine.cs:line 301
   at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.ExecuteTaskAsync(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, Stopwatch stopWatch, CakeTask task, CakeReport report) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeEngine.cs:line 311
   at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.RunTask(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, CakeTask task, String target, Stopwatch stopWatch, CakeReport report) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeEngine.cs:line 226
   at Cake.Core.CakeEngine.RunTargetAsync(ICakeContext context, IExecutionStrategy strategy, ExecutionSettings settings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\CakeEngine.cs:line 189
   at Cake.Cli.BuildScriptHost`1.RunTargetAsync(String target) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Cli\Hosts\BuildScriptHost.cs:line 73
   at Cake.Core.Scripting.ScriptHost.RunTarget(String target) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Scripting\ScriptHost.cs:line 105
   at Submission#0.<<Initialize>>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.ScriptExecutionState.RunSubmissionsAsync[TResult](ImmutableArray`1 precedingExecutors, Func`2 currentExecutor, StrongBox`1 exceptionHolderOpt, Func`2 catchExceptionOpt, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script`1.RunSubmissionsAsync(ScriptExecutionState executionState, ImmutableArray`1 precedingExecutors, Func`2 currentExecutor, Func`2 catchExceptionOpt, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Cake.Infrastructure.Scripting.RoslynScriptSession.Execute(Script script) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake\Infrastructure\Scripting\RoslynScriptSession.cs:line 90
   at Cake.Core.Scripting.ScriptRunner.Run(IScriptHost host, FilePath scriptPath) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake.Core\Scripting\ScriptRunner.cs:line 172
   at Cake.Features.Building.BuildFeature.RunCore(IRemainingArguments arguments, BuildFeatureSettings settings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake\Features\Building\BuildFeature.cs:line 99
   at Cake.Features.Building.BuildFeature.Run(IRemainingArguments arguments, BuildFeatureSettings settings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake\Features\Building\BuildFeature.cs:line 49
   at Cake.Commands.DefaultCommand.Execute(CommandContext context, DefaultCommandSettings settings) in C:\projects\cake\src\Cake\Commands\DefaultCommand.cs:line 73
```

Comment: Could you run `dotnet cake --verbosity=diagnostic` that should show a more details of the exception.

Comment: Thanks you right, with that I can see that it can't find `adb`, going to add it and check how that works with it.

Answer (score 1):

To identify a problem you need run with diagnostic verbosity: `dotnet cake --verbosity=diagnostic`(thanks @nils)

To add `adb` into your `$PATH` you can follow answers for this question: [Not able to access adb in OS X through Terminal, "command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609270/not-able-to-access-adb-in-os-x-through-terminal-command-not-found)

Now after that it runs without any problems:

```
Time Elapsed 00:00:07.18
!!! android APK /Users/***/bin/Debug/***-Signed.apk
Success
Performing Streamed Install
Success
```

Comment: Glad you found it.
FWIW: I filed an issue under https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Android.Adb/issues/10 since the error message is totally wrong.