# React-native app build successfully but crash on device when opening it

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

App crash on opening it on android device. Build successfully but raising an error "Failed to connect to development server".

Comment: run `npm start ` under your project directory and try to open the app.

Comment: Tried but still no improvement

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple issues with this.

1. Check that your node package mananger is running close it, connect
   your mobile and run the following command.

- `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
- `npx react-native start`

it my solve your problem.

second

2. if you want wireless debugging, shake your cellphone it will open the debug menu  click on the setting , find your ip address witht he command `ipconfig/all` and then click on **Debug server host & port for device** enter your **IP** like this `xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8081` and press R from your development server.

Hope this solve your porblem

Comment: adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 , after putting this command, it is saying. "zsh: command not found: adb"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7609270/9570734

Comment: check your path varaible. there is issue with your path varaibales. @VaishaliJain

Comment: you can accept and vpvote this answer. thanks