# 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I am trying to run google map v2 on emulator, I am following [this](http://hmkcode.com/run-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator/) tutorial.
When I was trying to install required apk file on emulator, I am getting below error.

I tried to solve this using [this](http://zacktutorials.blogspot.in/2013/04/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or.html) tutorial.Followed all steps, added the path to paltform-tools to  environment path. Also after modifying the PATH variable started a new CommandPrompt window.

But getting the same error. I need to check my google map application on emulator.
Kindly suggest me.

```
'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adb is not recognized as internal or external command on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744758/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command-on-windows)

Comment: My adb.exe path is C:\Users\Mis\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
 so you can set path your environment variable or traverse the folder and run your adb shell commands.

Comment: The generic path for Windows OS is %LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Answer (score 365, accepted):

Set the path of adb into System Variables. You can find adb in "**ADT Bundle/sdk/platform-tools**" Set the path and restart the cmd n then try again.

**Or**

You can also goto the dir where adb.exe is located and do the same thing if you don't wanna set the PATH.

If you wanna see all the paths, just do

```
echo %PATH%
```

Comment: Thank you .. set the path to system variables works , i was adding to user variables.

Comment: "restart the cmd " works for me. I was checking just adding path without restart.

Comment: no need to restart cmd like such: `PATH %PATH%;E:\Android\sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: and what if you use Genymotion?

Comment: find adb here: "USERNAME/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platform-tools"

Comment: if you just added a path variable, you may not see the the path just added. try signing out and signing again and recheck.

Comment: If you don't see AppData under your username make sure to check hidden items under view on top left.

Answer (score 337):

From Android Studio 1.3, the ADB location is at:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools.
```

Now add this location to the end of PATH of environment variables. Eg:

```
;C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

Comment: After we got adress, to add path in windows we should type in cmd:
`path C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`

Comment: Thankyou Vamsi sir, I am very grateful that you , this error is solved with this step

Comment: If you change the path to this `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools` it's copyable for everyone and will work the same.

Comment: Don't know why, but in my case restart was needed as well.

Answer (score 155):

If you want to use it every time add the path of adb to your system variables:
enter to cmd (command prompt) and write the following:

```
echo %PATH%
```

this command will show you what it was before you will add adb path

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools"
```

be careful the path that you want to add if it contains double quote

after you restart your cmd rewrite:

```
echo %PATH%
```

you will find that the path is added

PS: if you just want to add the path to cmd just to this session you can use:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools
```

Comment: Just a detail, remember to restart Android Studio after you set the %PATH% to your system. This solution should work as @Chris Sim suggested.

Comment: It deleted all my environment variables of Path. how can I bring them back?

Comment: If you us`setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools"` the old path will not be deleted!! , %PATH% is the old path that u already have, then you add you local path

Comment: there are possibility that path can be truncated to 1024 characters if you use setx via command line like this. I prefer use control panel forms in windows to edit paths

Comment: For proper workability command line should be launched as Administrator.

Comment: I followed these instructions using powershell. This screwed up all my previously set PATH variables. I followed the append instruction exactly. Warning to future people do not do this!

Answer (score 119):

I did this on Windows 7, by going to:

**Start** > **Control Panel** > **System** > **Advanced System Settings** > **Environment Variables...**

In this **Environment Variables** window, in the **User variables for (your-username)** highlight `Path` and click **Edit...**

You then need to append a `;` if there isn't already one at the end of the **Variable value** field, and then append `C:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;` to that same field.

Then click the three OK buttons to get out.

If you already have a **Command Prompt** window open, close it then re-open and the `adb devices` command should then work.

Comment: In my case, this one works when I set it to the one in `System Variables`

Answer (score 52):

In Windows 10,

1. Add User Variable PATH: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`.
2. Restart `cmd` (if any open).
3. `adb devices`, it should list, if it does, you are all set.

That's it!

Comment: This ^ It has to be in the _User Path_, not the _System Path_.

Comment: I think this is the clearest & least error-prone answer on this thread. should be the accepted answer

Comment: Restart cmd is important..+1

Answer (score 44):

On Window, sometimes I feel hard to click through many steps to find `platform-tools` and open `Environment Variables Prompt`, so the below steps maybe help

#### Step 1. Open cmd as Administrator

#### Step 2. File `platform-tools` path

```sh
cd C:\
dir /s adb.exe
```

[image]

#### Step 3: Edit Path in Edit Enviroment Variables Prompt

```sh
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

[image]

more, the command to open environment variables can not remember, so I often make an alias for it  (eg: `editenv`), if you need to work with environment variables multiple time, you can use a **permanent** doskey to make alias

#### Step 4: Restart cmd

Comment: Step 4: Restart computer - in my case helped. Thanks for good instruction!

Answer (score 36):

Add your path into environment variable "PATH" where you installed your sdk with below:

```
\Sdk\platform-tools
```

You can in image below for example:

[image]

and reopen your command prompt to see changes.

Comment: --> `andorid` 

Answer (score 34):

Follow path of you platform tools folder in android setup folder where you will found adb.exe

D:\Software\Android\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

Check the screenshot for details

[image]

Comment: I just found Android Studio folder in Android no android-sdk folder found why?

Answer (score 16):

If your OS is Windows, then it is very simple.
When you install Android Studio, adb.exe is located in the following folder:

```
C:\Users\**your-user-name**\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

Copy the path and paste in your environment variables.

Open your terminal and type: `adb` it's done!

Answer (score 15):

adb command can be under the new path below-
***C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools***
for new versions of Android studio.
I found in this location for me.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

For environment variable, we have to need to follow some steps.

Answer (score 14):

You will need to set the PATH variable pointing to the directory where `adb.exe` is to be found. If you are using `cmd.exe`, this command will help:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%\appdata\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

Answer (score 12):

In new version `PowerShell`, after all steps that mentioned before this, please attend:

**before**

```
adb
```

**now**

```
.\adb
```

Answer (score 10):

just open Android studio and press "Tools" on Top navigation bar

```
tools->SDK Manager
```

Where you can get SDK location

Open `SDK folder -> platform-tools`

Answer (score 9):

I recommand you using [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7)

Set Android Studio Terminal to PowerShell:

```
Settings > Tools > Terminal > Shell path = pwsh.exe (instead of cmd.exe)
```

Open Terminal on Android Studio

```
PowerShell 7.0.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

PS >
```

Test the path for adb.exe

```
# `pikachu` should be replace your username
PS > test-path "C:\Users\pikachu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools"
True
```

Open your powershell profile file in your text editor

```
PS > notepad $profile
```

add below line, save and exit

```
# `pikachu` should be replaced with your username
$env:PATH+=";C:\Users\pikachu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools"
```

re-open Terminal and try `adb`

```
PS > adb
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.1-6435776
Installed as C:\Users\hdformat\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

global options:
 -a         listen on all network interfaces, not just localhost
 -d         use USB device (error if multiple devices connected)
 -e         use TCP/IP device (error if multiple TCP/IP devices available)
 -s SERIAL  use device with given serial (overrides $ANDROID_SERIAL)
 -t ID      use device with given transport id
 -H         name of adb server host [default=localhost]
 -P         port of adb server [default=5037]
```

Comment: cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For 
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

Comment: This is so close... I had to add a semicolon before my path:

```
$env:PATH+=";C:\Users\pikachu\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools"
```

Answer (score 8):

1st: goto the drive where your eclipse reside and goto **sdk and platform** tool in my case *C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\platform-tools*

2nd:copy that address for ease of access

[image]

3:open command prompt **win+r** and type **cmd** hit enter

4:paste the address in cmd and hit enter thats all

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Since I installed version 1.0.41,

I  had to use the command **`"adb version"`**  instead of **`"adb –version"`**, in Windows 10.

[image]

Check and add these below loacations to the path variable:

C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools 
C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools 
C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools

ANDROID_HOME 
C:\Users\Sameera\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: Note that by default, the `AppData` folder is hidden on Windows 10, so you may need to unhide it first. See: https://support.captureone.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007574298-Unhiding-the-AppData-folder-on-Windows

Answer (score 6):

Based on [Vamsi Tallapudi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3424919/vamsi-tallapudi)s earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31760445/505701) I came up with this dynamic path:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%/Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

It's using a [Windows Environment Variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html). I find this solution to be both elegant and easy and would therefor like to share it.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem when I define **PATH** below

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin;C:\dev\sdk\android\platform-tools
```

and the problem solved when I bring adb root at first.

```
C:\dev\sdk\android\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45\bin
```

Answer (score 4):

This is where I found it:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

I had to put the complete path into the file explorer. I couldn't just click down to it because the directories are hidden.

I found this path listed in Android studio:

Tools > Android > SDK Manager > SDK Tools

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes that the PATH has been correctly set as described in the other answers.

If you're on Windows 10 and don't have Admin rights, then right click on the CMD, powershell ... program and select run as administrator. Then try adb [command]

Answer (score 2):

First select drive that is where Android sdk folder is there. Then you Follow the below steps

**cd DriveName:/ or Ex : cd c:/ Press 'Enter'**

then you will give the path that is adb console path is there in a platform-tools folder
so 
**cd Root Folder/inner root folder if there/Platform-tools Press 'Enter'** then it selects the adb directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't set a path for ADB, you can run `.\adb` instead of `adb` at `sdk/platformtools`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Avast antivirus detects `adb.exe` as a virus and adds it to it chest

Answer (score 2):

> Step 1

In **android studio**. Go to `File > Setting > Languages & Frameworks > Android Studio > SDK Tools`

**Install**

- Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)
- Android SDK Platform-Tools
- Google USB Driver

> Step 2

Go to *`windows search bar`* and **search** *`edit the system environment variables`*

Now **click** *`Environment Variables`*

**Select** `path` in `user variables` and press **edit**

Now, **create** a new path. Your path will be `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`

> Step 3

Now, re-open the **cmd** window. and run the `adb devices` command.

Answer (score 1):

For those using macOS, [this osxdaily.com article](http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/14/add-new-path-to-path-command-line/) shows several ways to add `adb` to the $PATH.

Here's the one I prefer:

1. Add a file named `adb` to `/etc/paths.d/` folder that just contains the path to adb's location:  `/Users/YourUserName/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/`

   In a Terminal window, `sudo vim /etc/paths.d/adb`
   -> enter the path and save the file.
2. Close/re-open Terminal in order for it to see the change.

Answer (score 1):

For windows

You can open the Environment Variables window by pressing the Windows key + R and then typing "SystemPropertiesAdvanced" and pressing Enter. On the Advanced tab, click the "Environment Variables" button.

after that click on path and paste path of adb

Answer (score 1):

Add in Environment Variables new path

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just drag the `adb.exe` on to the command prompt from `sdk/platformtools` and leave a space and type the command you want: `like logcat`.

It looks like this for me:

```
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130917\sdk\platform-tools.exe logcat
```

and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just added the below path to my system `environment variables`

```
C:\Users\[YOUR-USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

and boom! it starts working..! You can now use the `adb` command.

Answer (score 0):

Set the path of adb into System Variables-C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

To get the path for adb.exe by typing **adb** in any of the windows terminal

[image]

Add the path to System Variables,
Then restart the android studio

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload your mobile device first.