# Why am I facing error in launching of android sdk?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am new in android development.Maybe this is a simple issue but I am not getting it.I want to do some settings using android sdk manager.But when I click on the icon of sdk manager,I am getting following errors:

**[2014-09-08 16:57:54 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] '"F:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2014-09-08 16:57:54 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.**

Can anyone give me some idea about fixing this issue?? I am using eclipse juno version 4.2.1 and sdk version 23.0.2.I am using Windows 8 64 bit.

Comment: you downloded 64bit sdk, if your system OS is 64bit it will work. Other wise you should download 32bit sdk.

Comment: Thanks,but,I am using Windows 8 64 bit. I think its something different.

Comment: check your java class path

Answer (score 0):

refer this link this might be used 
['adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564514/adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)
Check you have given all the paths are correct