# which adb.exe to chose?

Tags: android, adb

Im having trouble getting adb to work, i keep getting [''adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564514/adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or), I found out i need to set my system path so i tried to locate adb.exe

I found it in three folfder:

- C:\Users\Sven\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
- C:\Users\Sven\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platform-tools
- C:\Users\Sven\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\platform-tools

How do i know which one to add to PATH? the date created looks almost the same.

Comment: Whichever one has the sdk you wish to use?  You have 3 copies on your PC, none of them labeled.  We have no way of knowing which is which.

Comment: @GabeSechan thats exactly my problem ;) I just updated android studio and this happend..

Comment: Probably some odd bug, but there's no way for us to really know.  I'd guess whichever is latest and see if it works.  Adb would probably work from any of the 3, the app itself isn't one that changes a whole lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't make much difference..
You can use whichever you like..I would suggest- *C:\Users\Sven\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\platform-tools* since this looks to to be latest if you go with "sdk2"