# Firebase not getting entry on console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have implemented firebase in my project, but I am not getting an entry in firebase console. I have been trying so many different ways. Anybody have any idea what's going wrong?
 i have implement like this.

```
firebaseAnalytics com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(c);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  //  bundle.putString("Category", ""+Category);
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, Category);
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, Category);
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, Category1+" Store");
    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
    firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);`
```

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? what do you mean by "not getting entry in fire base"? What you want to do and what is the problem?

Comment: Snippet here you code

Comment: Question is not clear at all here ! Describe in detail !

Comment: Not getting entry in firebase console . what you need in more detail ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view aggregrated statistics about your events in the Firebase console dashboards. These dashboards update periodically throughout the day.

For immediate testing, you can enable verbose logging to monitor logging of events by the SDK to help verify that events are being logged properly. This includes both automatically and manually logged events.

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

This command displays your events in the Android Studio logcat, helping you immediately verify that events are being sent.

For more information, visit the Firebase Analytics documentation for Android.

Comment: getting this error "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: @Himani - Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564514/adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or