# Android+FireBase Analytics 9.4.0 does not work at all

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

has anyone successfully used FireBase 9.4.0 in an Android project? I don't get any events, any sessions, nothing when I updated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160638/firebase-not-getting-entry-on-console check this

Comment: also check it - https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: I have already installed FireBase successfully with an earlier version... This is not my problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this to get events :

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Comment: I've checked this, seems to be okay. But I don't see any events or sessions on the FireBase console.

Comment: you get it after 24 hours.

Comment: It's been more than 24 hours and still nothing. I actually went back to 9.0.2  and I'm waiting for that to show up now.