# How do I execute an adb command in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, monkey

For example, I want to execute this command from this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html):

```
$ adb shell monkey -p your.package.name -v 500
```

How do I do it? Where do I enter the command? I've tried entering it into the terminal but it says that '$' is not recognized.

I also tried removing '$' but it then says that "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$` isn't part of the command.
Use `adb shell monkey -p your.package.name -v 500`

adb is the command you ran on your terminal.
For example:

```
adb devices
```

shows you the connected devices.

```
adb shell
```

Starts a remote shell in the target emulator/device instance.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html for more info about adb.

Comment: Now it says: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Did you install adb? (see the link above)
If you did, you probably using windows, in that case you need to define an Enviroment variable to run the adb from everywhere
EDIT: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564514/adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or

Comment: Then what will be the variable name and value? Thank you.

Comment: See the link above, they answer that question

Comment: You might need to set an environment variable if it's still not working.

Comment: Once I installed Android Studio, the location is `/home/<user>/Documents/platform-tools/adb`

Comment: Unless the question was edited after this answer was added, this answer misses the point, and I suspect upvotes are from folks who don't even know what adb is.  The asker clarified that removing "$" did nothing - he knows that it's a terminal command.  With modern Android Studio installs, there is often a disagreement between what adb version is side-installed with AS itself and what might be available system-wide (if any).  If there is no magic shell or drop down menu to access the platform tools that AS itself is using, the right answer is "You can't."

Comment: Doesn't answer anything. It really sucks that ADB is installed automatically but AS doesn't know the path in it's own terminal.

Comment: Location of `adb` on Windows with Android Studio installed is `AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`. If you don't want to add this to PATH you can cd to the directory and use the command there.