# App build Successful but App opening gone blank

Tags: react-native

The following error messages are shown after creating a build.

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
> Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
> See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 47s
> 315 actionable tasks: 314 executed, 1 up-to-date
> info Connecting to the development server...
> warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
> info Starting the app...
> 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> error Failed to start the app.
> Error: Command failed: adb shell am start -n com.menpani.laundry_live/com.menpani.laundry_live.MainActivity
> at makeError (D:\rith_laundry\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
> at Function.module.exports.sync (D:\rith_laundry\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
> at tryLaunchAppOnDevice (D:\rith_laundry\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\tryLaunchAppOnDevice.js:58:22)
> at D:\rith_laundry\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:104:39
> at Array.forEach ()
> at runOnAllDevices (D:\rith_laundry\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:102:48)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
> at async Command.handleAction (D:\rith_laundry\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
> info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Comment: You should provide more detail instead of only the error statement. However, from the error statement, `'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` So `adb` needs to be found from somewhere in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: adb.exe is placed under AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Comment: using these dependencies

Android Studio 3.5
SDK Build Tool 31-rc5
SDK Platform tools 31.0.2

Node 14.17.1
JDK 13.0.1

Comment: Set your adb using [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564514/adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564514/adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or) if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

created the entries in system variables for JDK_HOME and PLATFORM_TOOLS, above displaying errors has been cleared, app start running on phone but still going blank,

i have something different this time, kindly check either its gradle version issue?

Result Displayed as:

Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Infinix X695 - 11' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 45s
315 actionable tasks: 314 executed, 1 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "067682514L109008"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.menpani.laundry_live/.MainActivity }

Comment: If you have a different question, then post a new question. Answers are for answering the original question, not asking new ones.