# Why does Expo app freeze before the app loads

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to launch an app that I know worked a few weeks ago and I haven't changed anything in the code, but for some reason its not loading. I've tried using LAN vs tunneling and clearing the cache. Below are screenshots of my laptop and my iPhone:

[Laptop Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPJ5u.png)
[iPhone Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjIIu.png)

When it gets to this point, I can no longer ctrl+c to quit the program. In the laptop image, the last line "iOS node_modules\expo/AppEntry.js" is never the same percentage but its always between 5% and 6.9%. And in the iPhone image, I've tried running the exact command it gives me and I've quadruple checked that the wifi is the same on the laptop and the iPhone. I don't quite understand the AppDelegate part, but I've opened both of them and there is no URL anywhere.

I'm still fairly new to app development so if more information is needed I can provide it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IOS, you need an especfic the host machine

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://DEV_SERVER_URI:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

This command could you help you:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Comment: I don't understand what those lines do or how to use them. Could you please elaborate? I tried copy and pasting into the terminal of the root, but they both resulted in "the term jsCodeLocation/adb is not recognized"

Comment: Just need to ping @alonso

Comment: Did you fix it?. I think that the error is you don't have the necessaries "Environment Variables" in your system. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564514/adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or) to fix it

Comment: I am testing my app on an iPhone so the adb command did nothing useful. I've searched for where the jsCodeLocation variable is in the app files but I can't find it, I quick google search shows that other people say its inside the AppDelegate.m file. But when I search for that file in File Explorer, I don't see it.