# Failed to resolve the Android SDK path

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

I'm using `expo` to build a React Native app with VS Code.

I get this error when I press `a` to `open Android`.

> Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not
> found: C:\Users\sukesh.y\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME
> to set the Android SDK location. Error: 'adb' is not recognized as an
> internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

[image]

In my machine, the SDK path is `D:\Android\android-sdk`

I have added the environment variables like this, with no luck:

[image]

Then, I also added the same in React Native configurations like this. Same error again:

[image]

As mentioned in other solutions for same question, I could not find the "Android" folder or the "local.properties" file. I guess it will not be created when we use `expo`.

Comment: You need to set the path of adb into System Variables [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564514/adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or) mack sure that you have an emulator installed  in your system or you are running app in the real device then **use debugging  enable** in developer option

Comment: @RajParmar I have updated the path in env. variables to D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools. It's still the same error.

Comment: Refer to this link for solutions [TRY THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564514/adb-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)  I hope you set path in the system variables

Comment: @RajParmar I did add `D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools` in PATH. Now the error is `The system cannot find the path specified`

Comment: You path is wrong bro mine is you have to go in AppData Folder **C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools** and make sure that your platform-tools folder has adb.exe

Comment: I do not have any android folder in C:\users\appdata. The adb.exe does exist in D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

Comment: sorry my bad AppData is hidden by default