# "adb : The term 'adb' is not recognized" On windows

Tags: android, windows, environment-variables

Hi I am trying to setup adb for using expo client,

I have been following the instructions from here but i just couldnt get it to work...

> https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/android-studio-emulator/

Here is my Environment variables:

[image]

And the folder is actualy exists.

[image]

Also "adb" command totally works inside the folder.

[image]

but it doesnt work outside.

[image]

The problem is totally on the environment variables but i cant see it...

Comment: Please don't post terminal output as screenshot, just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code.

Comment: Have you tried to add the path where `adb.exe` is located to the `PATH`? Otherwise Windows will never be able to execute adb.exe if you don't specify the full path to `adb.exe`.

Comment: @Robert Okay! I will keep that in mind.
Also i tried to give the exact location too but sadly it did not work out :P

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44525706/208273 (note: it's `PATH`, not `ANDROID_HOME`)

Answer (score 0):

Chahge `ANDROID_HOME` from `C:\Users\berke\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` to `C:\Users\berke\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

My variables:

[image]

Comment: I have just tried that. Unfortunately it did not work :c.
I have checked the variable from cmd, here is the output.
<br>

C:\Users\berke>echo %ANDROID_HOME%
C:\Users\berke\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

C:\Users\berke>